# JQuery Form Plugin - Pass Object to Success Function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using the JQuery Form plug-in to send forms via Ajax. I cobbled together the code from various places and everything works perfectly, except one thing.

Upon `success` the data from the PHP processing file gets output to a `<div>` (i.e. the 'message sent' response). The ID of that `<div>` is currently set within the function. What I want to do is to be able to set that ID outside of the function so it is more easily re-usable, but I can't for the life of me work out how to pass that ID into the function. Because:

1. I cannot set any arguments in the `success:` section, I can only name the function.
2. I can't seem to be able to pass an argument any other way, i.e. I cannot add an extra argument to the success function, i.e. `writeOutput(data,divID)`, defining `divID` elsewhere.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$(formOne).ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        return $(formOne).validate({
            // validation rules
        }).form();
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        // beforeSend actions
    },
    success: writeOutput
});

function writeOutput(data) {

    var $out = $('#output');

    if (typeof data == 'object' && data.nodeType)
        data = elementToString(data.documentElement, true);
    else if (typeof data == 'object')
        data = objToString(data);

    $out.append('<div>'+ data +'</div>');
}
```

So how can I define the ID (which is currently #output) outside of the `writeOutput()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works and not a direct answer,

For "I cannot set any arguments in the success: section", you could do something like:

```
$(formOne).ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        return $(formOne).validate({
            // validation rules
        }).form();
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        // beforeSend actions
    },    
    success: writeOutput,
    context: { extra_arg: 'some_value' }
});

function writeOutput(data) {
    var extra_var_val = this.extra_var; //the extra argument
    var $out = $('#output');

    if (typeof data == 'object' && data.nodeType)
        data = elementToString(data.documentElement, true);
    else if (typeof data == 'object')
        data = objToString(data);

    $out.append('<div>'+ data +'</div>');
}
```

Whatever is passed into 'context' becomes the context of the callback function. Hope it works.